# How to get trade_offer_state from Steam's API GetTradeOffer

Tags: javascript, steam-web-api

I have an object `trade` returned from Steam's API [GetTradeOffer](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/IEconService#GetTradeOffer_.28v1.29) which contains the following:

```
tradeofferid=697052768, accountid_other=38044877, expiration_time=1443176120, trade_offer_state=7
```

if I `console.log(trade)` I get:

`tradeofferid=697052768, accountid_other=38044877, expiration_time=1443176120, trade_offer_state=7`

however if I do `console.log(trade.trade_offer_state)` I get `undefined`

Has anyone got any idea as to why?

EDIT:

Here is the full markup for this section:

```
function checkOffer(offer) {
    offers.getOffer({
        tradeOfferId: offer.trade_id.toString()
    }, function(err, trade) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        logger.info(trade);
        if (trade.trade_offer_state == '7' || trade.trade_offer_state == '4' || trade.trade_offer_state == '5' || trade.trade_offer_state == '6' || trade.trade_offer_state == '9' || trade.trade_offer_state == '10') {
            connection.query('UPDATE `trade_queue` SET `offer_sent` = 0 WHERE `id` = ' + "'" + offer.id + "'", function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                logger.info(rows[0]);
            });
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: `trade` is not an object, it's a string

Comment: Show us how you're adding that to the `trade` "object"

Comment: what does `console.log(typeof trade)` return?

Comment: @freefaller trade is returned from the GetTradeOffer (v1): https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/IEconService

Comment: @Reeno `console.log(typeof trade)` returns `object`

Comment: If that was an object [it would work](http://jsfiddle.net/5mg3q163/).

Comment: Assuming it's JSON, have you parsed it? `var obj = JSON.parse(json)`, for example?

Comment: what is `logger.info` doing ?

Comment: @karkael https://github.com/winstonjs/winston

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(JSON.stringify(trade))`?

Comment: @Torben `{"response":{"offer":{"tradeofferid":"697052768","accountid_other":38044877, "expiration_time":1443176120,"trade_offer_state":7,`

Comment: Where exactly do you insert the `console.log` calls? In the first line of the function, before or after `logger.info` or anywhere else?

Comment: @Torben `logger.info` acts as a `console.log()`: It outputs the following `Info: some output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object is:

```
var trade = {
    "response": {
        "offer": {
            "tradeofferid": "697052768",
            "accountid_other": 38044877,
            "expiration_time": 1443176120,
            "trade_offer_state": 7
        }
    }
}
```

Then you get your value using:

```
var val = trade.response.offer.trade_offer_state; // 7
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5mg3q163/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var trade = { 
    "tradeofferid": 697052768, 
    "accountid_other": 38044877, 
    "expiration_time": 1443176120, 
    "trade_offer_state": 7 
};

console.log( trade.trade_offer_state ); // same as
console.log( trade["trade_offer_state"] ); // both return 7
```

Comment: Still returns `undefined`

Comment: Did you run it on your console browser ?

Comment: @karkael Read the comments of the question. He get's the data from an external source, your answer doesn't work for him

Answer (score 0):

When `var trade = "tradeofferid=697052768, accountid_other=38044877, expiration_time=1443176120, trade_offer_state=7";`

You can add these lines:

```
function(err, trade) {
    eval.bind( this )( "var " + trade );
    trade = { 
        "tradeofferid": tradeofferid, 
        "accountid_other": accountid_other, 
        "expiration_time": expiration_time, 
        "trade_offer_state": trade_offer_state
    };
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    logger.info(trade);
    if (trade.trade_offer_state == '7' || trade.trade_offer_state == '4' || trade.trade_offer_state == '5' || trade.trade_offer_state == '6' || trade.trade_offer_state == '9' || trade.trade_offer_state == '10') {
        connection.query('UPDATE `trade_queue` SET `offer_sent` = 0 WHERE `id` = ' + "'" + offer.id + "'", function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            logger.info(rows[0]);
        });
    }
}
```

OR

```
function(err, trade) {
    eval( trade );
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    logger.info(trade);
    if (trade_offer_state == '7' || trade_offer_state == '4' || trade_offer_state == '5' || trade_offer_state == '6' || trade_offer_state == '9' || trade_offer_state == '10') {
        connection.query('UPDATE `trade_queue` SET `offer_sent` = 0 WHERE `id` = ' + "'" + offer.id + "'", function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            logger.info(rows[0]);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Forthemore, you can simply this line : `if( [7,4,5,6,9,10].indexOf( trade_offer_state ) != -1 ){ //...`.